# Is "on the pretext of" more correct than "under the pretext of" or vice versa?

Tags: word-usage

Is "under" or "on" more correct in this instance?

I would like to say "Sysco has had all the business for quite some time **under the pretext** of a program which they have been grandfathered into."

Comment: Sorry to point out how obviously using *or vice versa* has no meaning but an attempt to appear clever. 

*On…* or *… under the pretext of* are normally interchangeable. Why did you doubt that, please?

None of that is relevant to *Sysco has had all the business for quite some time under the pretext of a program which they have been grandfathered into.*

What you mean by *(anything) they have been grandfathered into* didn’t work.

*Under the pretext of a program… (anything)* also didn’t work.

If you’d appreciate some help, please take all of this to English Language Learners.

Comment: "Attempt to appear clever". You'll have to forgive me for not reading any of what you wrote following such a presumptuous statement. So you're so good at English you can read my motivation?  What a prick!  Who lets this guy post?  Very unprofessional.

Comment: Sorry, Jonathan. Less clearly, the Question as asked can't matter. *On* or *under* are here interchangeable; *pretext* is the problem.

You might, but not easily, make a case for *on/under a program…*; still the problem is *pretext*.

I'm still sorry and it's your choice whether to sort it out now or after you've published it under your name, and still the sentence you posted will seem to many of your English readers an attempt to appear clever.

For future reference yes, many if not most editors can read motivation in English. That’s partly why they’re journalists, let alone editors.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin just want to point out that you still sound like a major prick.  Does saying “or vice versa” not mean or the reverse?  Why does that not function here?  I can’t get over how much of a prick you are.

Comment: Sorry, Jonathan… whether you like it or not, it remains true that “on the pretext of” is at best very little more correct than “under the pretext of” and since there is a tiny difference, "vice versa" can't apply.

If any of this is truly interesting, why not take it somewhere like English Language Learners?

If you'd rather have an argument, why not say so?

Comment: Why can vice verse not apply to tiny differences?  And I still don’t understand how the use of a phrase so conventional as “vice verse” could be construed as an *obvious* attempt to seem clever.  And if you’ve known all along that “on the pretext of” is “at best very little more correct”, why couldn’t you have just answered the gd question 3 years ago when I asked it?!  Will you please explain to me why the problem is with pretext?  If someone can operate on/under an assumption, why not on/under a pretext?  Aren’t they both kinds of propositions?

Comment: Sorry, Jonathan… vice verse applies where there are no other differences; to black against white, but never to any kind of grey. Does that make sense to you, or not?

Comment: Maybe that’s what it has come to mean within the walls of the academy (and I’m happy to know that it has such a technical meaning), but more broadly I’m sure no one would argue that the majority of people use it within such constraints.  Just google it. I wish I still had a subscription to the OED.  One thing I’ve learned from all this is that the comments section of SE sure can be dog-eat-dog, or vice verse.

Comment: In 60 years of listening I've never once heard "vice versa" used to mean anything but ”the other way round…" and that always specifically, never generally or vaguely.

If you can explain how that includes grey shades - your "tiny differences" - on top of black and white, opposites, please do.

In your example "Vice versa" could apply mechanically. To make that linguistic would stretch too much.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin will you answer this question?